# Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python, arrays, object

I created an enemy class that reads data from a file to get its instance variables. 
The file is written to different arrays for the different types of enemies. They work fine. When I write them to the object then try to print them I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

If I don't print the 'type' attribute then it says:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'health'
```

The class is:

```
def Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, TypeStats):
        self.type = TypeStats[0][0]
        self.health = int(TypeStats[0][1])
        self.strength = int(TypeStats[0][2])
        self.dead = False
```

The code to write the array to the object and print the variables is:

```
Bandit = Enemy(BanditStats)
print Bandit.type, Bandit.health, Bandit.strength
```

The reason I write it as a 2D array is because when I write the data from the file to the array it creates an array:

```
BanditStats = [['Bandit', '80','7']]
```

I don't know why that happens is it easy to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define classes using `def`. It should be `class`:

```
class Enemy:
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did that a second time with another class just now.

Comment: When I was on it said I had to wait a few more minutes to accept it.